# Python regex extract vimeo id from url

Tags: python, regex, url, vimeo

```
embed_url = 'http://www.vimeo.com/52422837'
response = re.search(r'^(http://)?(www\.)?(vimeo\.com/)?([\/\d+])', embed_url)
return response.group(4)
```

The response is:

```
5
```

I was hoping for

```
52422837
```

Anybody an idea? I'm really bad with regexes :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\d+` (no brackets) to match the literal slash + digits:

```
response = re.search(r'^(http://)?(www\.)?(vimeo\.com/)?(\d+)', embed_url)
```

Result:

```
>>> re.search(r'^(http://)?(www\.)?(vimeo\.com/)?(\d+)', embed_url).group(4)
'52422837'
```

You were using a character group (`[...]`) where none was needed. The pattern `[\/\d+]` matches exactly one of `/`, `+` or a digit.

Answer (score 10):

Don't reinvent the wheel!

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://www.vimeo.com/52422837')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.vimeo.com', path='/52422837', params='',
query='', fragment='')

>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://www.vimeo.com/52422837').path.lstrip("/")
'52422837'
```

Comment: It is possible the OP is searching in a larger body of text instead.

Comment: The variable name suggests that OP is searching a URL.

Comment: What if it is a simplified example for the purposes of the question (which would be a smart thing to do when asking a question on SO)?

Comment: okay.. this one is indeed better. Didn't know about urlparse.. diving in it now ;D.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get everything after the last slash (assuming there is one) the following simple regex should do it:

```
[^/]*$
```

(Greedily grabs everything up to the end that isn't a slash.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried finishing your regexp with a dollar ($) symbol?